# VNC Viewer terminal and folders are not working. Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, gnome-terminal, vnc-server, vnc-viewer

I am having a very hard time fixing the problem.
I tried to open Ubuntu16.04 in Vnc4server. But when I opened the Vnc Viewer I can not
open my terminal or anyother applications like firefox as shown in the image below!!!.

[image]

There is only that Home Directory. No Icons and terminal icons..
I don't know how to fix this really. I tried all the VNC4server settings.
This is my nano ~/.vnc/xstartup settings below image. 
I used command vnc4server -geometry 1500x1000 :96 and opened as display 96.
Does anyone know how to fix this?? I've been struggling this for a day.
I really need great help. Thanks in advance!

[image]